# How to fix the logcat problem in Android studio dolphin?

Tags: android-studio, logcat

I like the new logcat display in Android Studio Dolphin .. when it works.

For example, one thing that used to be very annoying in the past was that in many cases of app crashing, the logcat display would be reset, so you couldn't see the exception that happened, whereas with the new display, you can often see the exception.

However, what is annoying is the problem that appears randomly: you run an app from Android Studio and hope to see logs in logcat. Instead, there would be a `studio.deploy` error, something like

`Could not remove dir '/data/data/<packageName>/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory'`

and then no further logs would be shown.

This has been reported months ago in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243496470?pli=1 , but doesn't appear to have been resolved. Workarounds suggested in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243496470?pli=1 , such as restarting Android Studio, appear to not work sometimes, in what seems to be a random way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the answers in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243496470?pli=1 works consistently.

> But by random I saw that under "Edit Configuration" the Launch Option was "Nothing". Obviously, that was the error and as I switched to "Default Activity" the activity was starting.